# Problems with FileOutputStream

Tags: java, io

Why does this code cause an error: `access denied`?

```
public void armazenaPerfil() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {    
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(this.login + "_perfil.mbk");
    ObjectOutputStream objOut = new ObjectOutputStream(out);          
    objOut.writeObject(this);
    System.out.println("Escrevi!");
    objOut.close();
}
```

The error message:

```
ric93_perfil.mbk(acess denied)

java.io.FileNotFoundException

at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)

at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:212)

at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:104)

at br.uefs.ecomp.myBook.model.Perfil.armazenaPerfil(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Can you include the actual error message?

Comment: Do you have permission to write to that file?

Comment: If you're getting an Exception, please include more of the Exception output in the question body.

Comment: 1) Exact error message, please.  2) Where exactly are you writing the file?  Do you have permissions to write there???

Comment: I don't know where the file is written

Comment: Try this to figure out where you're writing to: `System.out.println(new File(this.login + "_perfil.mbk").getAbsolutePath());`

Answer (score 1):

Access denied problems are basically the operating system saying "You are not allowed to write that".  Basically, an OS-level access control / permissions issue is preventing you from reading or writing the file at the specified location.

When you write a file using a relative pathname, the JVM will attempt to write it in a location relative to the running application's current working directory.  What directory that will be depends on how the JVM is launched, but if you launch from a command prompt using the `java` command, it will be the command shell's current directory.

You can find out what the current director actually is using the one-liner suggested by Brendan Long:

```
System.out.println(new File(pathname).getAbsolutePath());
```

where `pathname` is the pathname of the file you were trying to read or write.  Note that this doesn't actually check that the pathname refers to an existing file, or tell you that you should be able to create or open the file.  It *merely* tells you what the absolute pathname for the file *would* be.